# Punctured phone battery

Tags: batteries

My old phone stopped working. We threw it around and beat it with rocks for 20 minutes until the back came off and revealed the battery. It was all swollen.

We started picking it with a stick until we punctured it. We googled what to do in this situation. One post wrote to put it in salt water and wait for it to discharge and then throw it in a regular battery dispose can that you find in supermarkets. I did what it said and **placed it in an old jar with salt water. Bubbles started coming out from it and small black pieces crumbled to the bottom of the jar**.

What should we do now?

Comment: Your text is a "wall of text" and that makes it very hard to read, split it up in a few paragraphs (just a few <Enter> here and there) to make it more readable. Also this site is about **electronic design** and your question is about how to handle after doing stupid things which isn't very on-topic.

Comment: now u should post a reaction video on utube and wait for the views to pour in. buy a new phone with the ad revenue u get

Comment: Step one: don't do everything you did do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wait a week and dispose of the battery at your locally hazardous waste disposal center.

- A swollen battery pouch contains gasses due to aging or overloading. This is a stable state. Although continuing to use the battery is not recommended.
- An opened battery pouch allows oxygen to enter, which may cause a mild exothermic reaction. As in, it becomes a bit warm and may smoke or smoulder.
- A punctured battery (as in, straight trough with a nail or knife) often causes a short circuit in the battery layers, which causes very high current, the electrolyte to evaporate very fast, the pouch to burst open, and since it was very hot, combustion of the evaporated electrolyte and often also ignition of the lithium cobalt-oxide. (aka a battery fire)

The electrolyte and the fumes are toxic, do no breathe.

Water is a safe method to prevent flames or cool a pack to prevent triggering other cells in thermal runaway, which is melting of the polymers between electrodes causing a short circuit again, see above.
Especially with small batteries submerging them completely contains the risk to a small area and prevents flames.

Water will not cause an [alkali reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water-reactive_substances) everyone is afraid of. This only happens with non-rechargable lithium batteries.

The black residue you see is the lithium cobalt oxide.

[image]

---

[Bonus slow motion x-ray footage of battery puntcture.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O_tzETWEnxc)